# EFcore where clause with custom function to determine type of comparison

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, translate

###### What I'm trying to do

I have a repository function that I want to be able support searching by string `Equals`, `Contains`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`. I've created a simple extension method that wraps around these string functions, but EFCore seems unable to translate this.

Are there are any alternative, reusable approaches similar to this?

###### How I'm trying to do it

```cs
public enum StringComparisonType
{
    Equals,
    Contains,
    BeginsWith,
    EndsWith
}
```

```cs
public static bool CompareTo(this string inputText, string comparisonText, StringComparisonType comparisonType) => comparisonType switch
{
    StringComparisonType.Equals => inputText.Equals(comparisonText),
    StringComparisonType.BeginsWith => inputText.StartsWith(comparisonText),
    StringComparisonType.Contains => inputText.Contains(comparisonText),
    StringComparisonType.EndsWith => inputText.EndsWith(comparisonText),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"{nameof(StringComparisonType)} {comparisonType} not currently supported.")
};
```

```cs
var searchText = "hello";
var comparison = StringComparisonType.BeginsWith;
_context.Records.Where(r => r.Text.CompareTo(searchText, comparison))
```

###### The problem with the approach

This throws an error along the lines of:

> The LINQ expression could not be translated

###### Alternative approach

The only alternative I've found that works is just inlining the logic to determine the type of comparison to apply, but this is horrible to read, horrible to write, and is not reusable, e.g.

```cs
_context.Records
    .Where(r => comparison == StringComparisonType.Equals 
        ? r.Text.Equals(searchText) 
        : comparison == StringComparisonType.BeginsWith 
            ? r.Text.StartsWith(searchText) 
            : comparison == StringComparisonType.EndsWith 
                ? r.Text.EndsWith(searchText) 
                : r.Text.Contains(searchText))
```

I'm currently using EFCore 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use it on predefined type (be `Record` in example) try something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<Record> WhereCompare(this IQueryable<Record> query, string comparisonText, StringComparisonType comparisonType) => comparisonType switch
{
    StringComparisonType.Equals => query.Where(r => r.Text.Equals(comparisonText)),
    StringComparisonType.BeginsWith => query.Where(r => r.Text.StartsWith(comparisonText)),
    StringComparisonType.Contains => query.Where(r => r.Text.Contains(comparisonText)),
    StringComparisonType.EndsWith => query.Where(r => r.Text.EndsWith(comparisonText)),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"{nameof(StringComparisonType)} 
             {comparisonType} not currently supported.")
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var result = _context.Records.WhereCompare(searchText, comparison).ToList();
```

### Generic method

Maybe this can be done easier, but let's do this. First implement Compose function (combine sequence of expressions into one):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

...

private static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> Compose<TSource, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TSource, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var intermediateValue = first.Body.ReplaceParameter(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var body = second.Body.ReplaceParameter(second.Parameters[0], intermediateValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(body, param);
}

private static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression,
    ParameterExpression toReplace,
    Expression newExpression)
{
    return new ParameterReplaceVisitor(toReplace, newExpression)
        .Visit(expression);
}
private class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression from;
    private Expression to;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : node;
    }
}
```

With this methods we can now create this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereCompare<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string comparisonText, StringComparisonType comparisonType)
{
    var filter = Compose<T, string, bool>(selector, WhereCompareSelector<T>(comparisonText, comparisonType));
    return query.Where(filter);
}

public static Expression<Func<string, bool>> WhereCompareSelector<T>(string comparisonText, StringComparisonType comparisonType) => comparisonType switch
{
    StringComparisonType.Equals => r => r.Equals(comparisonText),
    StringComparisonType.BeginsWith => r => r.StartsWith(comparisonText),
    StringComparisonType.Contains => r => r.Contains(comparisonText),
    StringComparisonType.EndsWith => r => r.EndsWith(comparisonText),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"{nameof(StringComparisonType)}{comparisonType} not currently supported.")
};
```

Usage:

```
var result = _context.Records.WhereCompare(t => t.Text, searchText, comparison).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice one, works a treat! I'm gonna hold off accepting your answer while I play around to try and get a more reusable approach to work. This is nice and can be re-used for all `Record` entities, but would be awesome if this function can be made even more generic and used for any entity.

Comment: I added genetic way to do it. But also left original method for people who not familiar with generics. Its T N answer but with fix and a bit explanation.

Comment: Your generic approach doesnt seem to compile for me. Has error `Method name expected` where `selector` is invoked. Is this meant to be `selector.Compile()(r)` instead of `selector(r)`? (I'm not familiar with Expressions at all. While `selector.Compile()(r)` compiles successfully, it hits the same runtime error, `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Answer>()
    .Where(a => Invoke(__Compile_0, a).Contains(__comparisonText_1))' could not be translated`

Comment: Added one more complex variant. Checked that its compile now. Try this and let me know. `Compose` method not mine, found while ago on stackoverflow and use for few years.

Comment: Very nice. Works like a charm. Now I'd going to need to spend more time looking into Expressions to understand how this works :D Thank you for this!